# Wrong git user commits are lost

Tags: github

I was doing commits as I was developing a project for sometime. But later I discovered I was committing under the wrong GitHub user. So, before I pushed my project to GitHub I changed my credentials, but when I published the project, it shows the wrong user as a contributor. Is there a way to associate all the commits with the right user only?

Answer (score 1):

#### How to correct your past commits to be associated with YOUR account

**Important no**te — I have only performed this on projects where I am the only contributor. It is not advised to perform this batch update action on a repo where you are collaborating with others as the action is destructive to the whole repo’s history! You’ve been warned!

**Step 1** — Open up Terminal

**Step 2** — ‘cd’ into wherever your project file is sitting

**Step 3** — Create a clone of your repository

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/user/repo.git
cd repo.git
```

**Step 4** — Copy and paste this script and replace OLD_EMAIL, CORRECT_NAME and CORRECT_EMAIL with the correct information.

```
#!/bin/sh
git filter-branch --env-filter '
OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

##### How to check for the “OLD_EMAIL”:

**Step 4a** — In your command line, enter $ git log --pretty=“format:%ae” to get a list of all email addresses associated with all past commits for this repo

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiBkB.png)

**Step 4b** — Therefore I will assign the variable OLD_EMAIL = “github email address”

**Step 5** — Hit Enter
A successful update looks like this (each branch in the repo will be rewritten):

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S1g2.png)

**Step 6** — Push the corrected history to your original repository:

```
git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'
```

What a successful push looks like:

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXWxa.png)

**Step 7** — Remove the temporary clone from your machine

```
cd ..
rm -rf repo.git
```

**Step 8** — Check your repo on GitHub to check if the commit details have been successfully updated. You should be able to see your correct username against each commit but more importantly — all the green squares!